# Run multiple commands in TeXShop typeset

Tags: biblatex, compiling, automation, texshop, mla-style

I am a user of `biblatex-mla` and I wish to run the whole bibliography generation workflow with a single click of "Typeset" in TeXShop.

```
pdflatex filename.tex
bibtex filename
pdflatex filename.tex
```

How can I run these commands in a single click of "Typeset"?

Comment: have you looked at `arara`?

Comment: You can always define your own engine, but I'm pretty sure there is  a default one which does just what you expect: you should try the `pdflatexmk` Engine.

Comment: @cmhughes Can you give a portal that compatible with MacTex?

Comment: @Corentin could you give a more specific guide of how to configure it?

Comment: @BenLu I believe that `arara` should ship with the latest update [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)

Comment: There are instructions for how to use `arara` in TeXshop in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/arara/doc/arara-usermanual.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install `arara`, in Preference pane of TeXShop, set Misc -> Personal Script to `arara`, add

```
%arara: pdflatex
%arara: bibtex
%arara: pdflatex
```

before the document in .tex file.

"Typeset" -> DONE!