# Need to Typeset twice for correct compile?

Tags: compiling, texshop

Whenever I press CMD+T in `TexShop`, the PDF created is not always updated correctly. I usually have to re-compile it to update the Table Of Contents and other changes I have made. How can I fix this ?

Using MACOSX 10.8 - TEXSHOP 3.11

Comment: You can't, really, that's just how it is. See for example [What are the situations where you have to compile a document more than once?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35832)

Comment: On the other hand, there are several tools for automatic compilation, so that you only have to press one button, and all necessary compilation runs are made. See [Tools for automating document compilation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64) for a list.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't. LaTeX has to build the `.aux` file to store the table of content (ToC) and such, because when typesetting the ToC it can't know beforehand what sections will occur. LaTeX works sequentially.

- *First run:* collect all sections and such and store it in `.aux` file.
- *Second run:* Use `.aux` file to typeset the ToC.

Actually it does both things at once: typset with the already existing .aux file (which can be empty or non-existant) and create an updated one for the next run.

There exist tools that "simulate" a "one-compile-all-get" behaviour, like `Texify` from MiKTeX for Windows. But normally all they do is just run the compiler twice in a row (maybe with `bibtex` inbetween if you use it).

Thanks to Torbjørn T. here are the links from his comments:

- [What are the situations where you have to compile a document more than once?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35832/what-are-the-situations-where-you-have-to-compile-a-document-more-than-once)
- [Tools for automating document compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tools-for-automating-document-compilation)

Answer (score 10):

This behaviour is normal for any TeX engine (as explained in [Foo Bar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19287/foo-bar)'s answer), but [Tools for automating document compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64/15717) might  automate the multiple runs of creating a LaTeX document when required.

I'd suggest user friendly automation tool `arara`: the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/arara/doc/arara-usermanual.pdf) is very well written for newbies! In particular, I'd like to point out that, it is possible to integrate `arara` with TeXShop, cf. section 4.4 pg. 41 of the linked manual.

[Ben Lu's Answer to "Run multiple commands in TeXShop"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97926/15717)

PS: This package is maintained by the author, [Paulo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094/paulo-cereda), who is also a distinguished member of TeX.SX community.