# ToC and lists of theorems (XeLaTeX)

Tags: table-of-contents, compiling

Why is it that if I make a change that should be reflected either in a table of contents or in a list of theorems, I need to typeset twice before getting the change reflected? My TeX Live utility is version 1.01, Copyright 2008-2012: is there a more recent version, and could an update eliminate this problem?

Comment: That's just how things work, the change is written to an external file on the first compilation, and on the second the updated file is read.

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107967/need-to-typeset-twice-for-correct-compile and the linked questions. (Edit: This is a duplicate of that question I guess, if you agree we'll close this.)