# What does "typeset twice" mean?

Tags: formatting

I am learning latex, and a book I am eading says that in order to renumber equations properly (after addition/removal), I need to typeset twice. Does does "typeset twice" mean?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.
Calling `pdflatex`, `latex`, `lualatex` or whatever compiler you use, twice is typesetting twice.

Comment: "typeset" is the wrong word. It should be "compile", or "run (La)TeX" or "build". The numbering of equations will be correct after one run. The thing changing for the second one will be the references and your ToC, LoF...

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Some editors use 'typeset'. I tend to use 'typeset' because that's what I learnt first. I disagree that it is wrong. In a sense, it is the specific kind of compilation relevant to TeX.

Comment: This is more like a meta question. :)

Comment: There was already a question using the term «typeset» as a synonym of «compile»: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107967/need-to-typeset-twice-for-correct-compile

Answer (score 4):

Here "typeset" means "run `latex filename` (or `pdflatex filename`) to produce a `.dvi` (or `.pdf`) file". It is a slightly unusual term; "compile" is more common.