# Can I bypass having to compile LaTeX twice?

Tags: pdftex, compiling, auxiliary-files

I read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107967/need-to-typeset-twice-for-correct-compile?newreg=8f0975cf97d646fc9aaf29a0b716966e) that sometimes we *must* compile twice in order for the .aux file to allow sectioning to function properly in the typesetting process.

My question is: if we manually delete the .aux file after a successful compilation, then edit the document, then compile again, will we have bypassed the need to compile twice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no \ref  or longtable or \include or tables of contents etc will work

Comment: Unless you write the entire document in one session and never need to run latex to preview the output until the document is complete, running latex more than once is not an issue. You almost always run latex more than once in any case while writing a document.

Comment: You need to compile multiple times because the later runs need to read the `.aux` file. So if you delete the `.aux` file, you have to compile more often (since you first need to regenerate it).

Comment: If you manually delete the `.aux` file, you'll *need* (at least) two runs of LaTeX, unless you have nothing that gets written in the `.aux` file.