# the 'proper' way to cite the earliest publication date in brackets, followed by the publication date of the recent version used – ASA style

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing

**See update on 2013-11-12 10:26:36Z below regarding my final solution**

In the American Sociological Association Style Guide. 3rd ed. (p. 2) [link, PDF!](http://www.asanet.org/students/Quick%20Style%20guide.pdf) it is explained and demonstrated how to cite a work that is reprinted from a version published earlier.

It should, according to [the ASA guide](http://www.asanet.org/students/Quick%20Style%20guide.pdf), look like this,

[image]

I'm curious to learn if there is an official or 'proper' way of doing this using `biblatex`? I have produced the above example with the code below,

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
style=authoryear, natbib=true, 
        ]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{bibfile.bib}

@book{Veblen2005:1899,
    Author = {Veblen, Thorstein},
    Isbn = {9788187879299},
    Language = {en},
    Month = jan,
    Publisher = {Aakar Books},
    Title = {{The Theory of the Leisure Class; An Economic Study of Institutions}},
    Year = {[1899] 2005}}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\ldots \citep{Veblen2005:1899} stated that \ldots\\

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

### Update on 2013-11-12 10:26:36Z

Switching backend from `bibtex` to `biber`, as suggested in [moewe's answer below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/143004/22939), proved to be a bit more challenging than expected as I couldn't use `biber` directly from `TeXShop` ([Ver. 3.26](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/changes_3.html) on OSX 10.8.5). However, I managed, with the help of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125229/22939) by [Harish Kumar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11232/harish-kumar), to use [arara](http://cereda.github.io/arara/). Thus solution did require me to add some *arara-lines* to the .tex file just before the `\documentclass{}` and to compile my .tex file from the terminal, I've pasted my code and a screenshot below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Veblen2005:1899,
    author = {Veblen, Thorstein},
    Isbn = {978-81-87879-29-9},
    publisher = {Aakar Books},
    title = {The Theory of the Leisure Class},
    subtitle = {An Economic Study of Institutions},
    date = {2005-01},
    origyear = {1899}}

@book{Weber2013,
    Author = {Weber, Max},
    Isbn = {9781135973988},
    Keywords = {Reference / General, Religion / General},
    Language = {en},
    Month = jul,
    Publisher = {Routledge},
    Title = {{The Protestant Ethic and the Spirit of Capitalism}},
    Year = {2013},
       origdate = {1905}}    
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
      \iffieldundef{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
        {}
        {\printtext[parens]{%
           \iffieldundef{origyear}% this is new ...
             {}
             {\printtext[brackets]{\printorigdate}
              \setunit{\addspace}}% ... till here
           \iffieldsequal{year}{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
             {\printdateextralabel}%
             {\printfield{labelyear}%
              \printfield{extrayear}}}}}%
    \renewbibmacro*{date}{}%
    \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
      \iffieldundef{issue}
        {}
        {\printtext[parens]{\printfield{issue}}}%
      \newunit}

    \renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
      \iffieldundef{labelyear}
        {}
        {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%moved this
          \iffieldundef{origyear}% this is new
            {}
            {\printtext[brackets]{\printorigdate}
             \setunit{\addspace}}% everything beyond this point is old
          \printfield{labelyear}%
          \printfield{extrayear}}}}

\usepackage{hyperref}
            \hypersetup{
          pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}, % thanks, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26085/22939
         }

% arara: pdflatex 
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex 
\begin{document}
\ldots \citep{Veblen2005:1899} stated that \ldots\\

However \citet{Weber2013} demonstrates that \ldots

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'll update this answer when I learn bore about the *backend* and *TeXShop*. Please feel free to comment if you know of a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: Seeing that you use TeXShop, you might like [In TeXShop, is there a directive to select biber or BibTeX on a per-document basis?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38348/35864) and [Dummies Guide to Biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63308/35864), to compile from TeXShop directly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `biblatex` way is to use `origdate`, but the default styles do not support `origdate` awfully well.

You might like the following redefinitions. This will work for the standard `mergedate=compact` option of `biblatex`.

We just add a call to `\printorigdate` where appropriate and make sure that `origdate` is not used as `labeldate` to avoid duplication.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{urldate}
  \literal{nodate}
}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \iffieldundef{origyear}
         {}
         {\printtext[brackets]{\printorigdate}%
          \setunit{\addspace}}%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \iffieldundef{origyear}
         {}
         {\printtext[brackets]{\printorigdate}%
          \setunit{\addspace}}%
       \printlabeldateextra}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Veblen2005:1899,
  author    = {Veblen, Thorstein},
  isbn      = {978-81-87879-29-9},
  publisher = {Aakar Books},
  title     = {The Theory of the Leisure Class},
  subtitle  = {An Economic Study of Institutions},
  date      = {2005-01},
  origdate  = {1899},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\ldots \citep{Veblen2005:1899,wilde} stated that \ldots

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Note that the `.bib` entry should be using `origdate` instead of `origyear` (generally, only the `...date` fields are supposed to appear in the `.bib` file, the backend parses the dates and produces the dateparts `...day`, `...month` etc., there are backwards compatibility exceptions for `year` and `month`, which are acceptable instead of `date`).

*edit* Updated for recent versions of `biblatex` and Biber. See the edit history for older versions.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question. I can't get your example to work. I run your MWE (? Working Example) and I get an error that I solved by reading the [documentation to the filecontents (PDF!)](http://get-software.net/macros/latex/contrib/filecontents/filecontents.pdf) and removing the `\` from the `filecontents` command, but I still can't figure it out. I am wondering why you have an Oscar Wilde reference in the screenshot you attached, but not in the code? Do the MWE work in a clean dir for anyone else? Thanks, Eric

Comment: @EricFail Yes, I'm sorry the picture did indeed not show the output one got from the code snippet, I have update the latter accordingly. I did not have any problem with `filecontents` though. One problem you might be facing is related to the BibTeX/Biber dichotomy: Your MWE used `backend=bibtex` while I had to use `backend=biber` to get the output you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, It took me some time to get the `biker` backend to run, but I've now marked your answer as the solution and updated my question a bit in case someone is in a similar situation. Would you share what software you are using to create your PDF file?

Comment: I used [`latexmk`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/) (called from TeXworks) to compile the document.

Comment: In case someone else has similar problems: replace `\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}` with `\begin{filecontents*}[force]{\jobname.bib}` when experimenting with the `.bib` file. If you don't want parentheses around the year (some journals request you remove them), replace `\printtext[parens]{%` with `\printtext{%` in the `date+extradate` macro

Answer (score 2):

Since the above answer is outdated and I struggled a bit to replicate this behavior in the biblatex `authoryear` style, I'll provide here the updated code. This works in biber version 2.12:

```
\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
      \iffieldundef{origyear}% new code
        {}
        {\printtext[brackets]{\printorigdate}\setunit{\addspace}}% end new
        \printlabeldateextra}}}%

\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \iffieldundef{origyear}% new code
        {}
        {\printtext[brackets]{\printorigdate}\setunit{\addspace}}% end new
        \printlabeldateextra}}}
```

Therefore the MVE becomes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Veblen2005:1899,
    author = {Veblen, Thorstein},
    Isbn = {978-81-87879-29-9},
    publisher = {Aakar Books},
    title = {The Theory of the Leisure Class},
    subtitle = {An Economic Study of Institutions},
    date = {2005-01},
    origyear = {1899},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
      \iffieldundef{origyear}% new code
        {}
        {\printtext[brackets]{\printorigdate}\setunit{\addspace}}% end new
        \printlabeldateextra}}}%

\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \iffieldundef{origyear}% new code
        {}
        {\printtext[brackets]{\printorigdate}\setunit{\addspace}}% end new
        \printlabeldateextra}}}

\begin{document}
\ldots \textcite{Veblen2005:1899} stated that \ldots

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Hope this helps anyone who'll struggle with this again!

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I modernised the code in my answer as well. I took a slightly different approach with respect to `date+extradate` to stay closer to the definition with `mergedate=compact`.