# How to compile \nomencl in order to have a list of abbreviation?

Tags: compiling, acronyms, texshop, nomenclature

I am quite new in LaTeX and I am using it to write my master thesis. Everything works quite fine until I wanted to make a list of abbreviations. I read most I could, including the nomencl package documentation and a lot of subjects here, but I still can't understand how to compile it.

I'm using TeXShop on Mac and I have the main page with the code and a smaller window of command, that displays any mistake when I typeset, for instance. My code is the following :

```
    \documentclass{article}
    %other packages
    \usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
    \renewcommand{\nomname}{Abbreviations}
    \makenomenclature 

    \begin{document}
    %title and other stuffs

    \newpage
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
    \tableofcontents
    \printnomenclature

   %Then some example of my abbreviations : 
   \section{Experimental Part}
   \textit{Synthesis of some compound \textbf{(aa)} \cite{FAP}}\\ %E13
    To a solution of 2-bromo-5-methoxybenzoic acid in DMF \nomenclature{DMF}{Dimethylformamide} (33 mL) is added CuCN\nomenclature{CuCN}{Copper Cyanide}. 

    \end{document}
```

When I compile it, even twice as for other commands, nothing appears, not even a blank page. And I can't type in my command window, so impossible to type the command :

```
makeindex master thesis.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o master thesis.nls
```

recommanded by the nomencl package documentation.

Comment: This may not be your problem but possibly a duplicate of [Using package nomencl](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27824/using-package-nomencl)

Comment: Haven't tested that, but maybe your file-name shouldn't contain a whitespace. You may try your `makindex` command with just "thesis.tex".

Comment: Seems like you have to define your own engine in TeXShop. You have to tell TeXShop the routine of `pdflatex`, `makeindex thesis.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o thesis.nls` and `pdflatex`. Just search this site for TeXShop and nomencl. I guess arara is the easier approach.

Answer (score 2):

May I recommend the tool "[arara](https://github.com/cereda/arara)"?

Just use the following MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
%other packages
\usepackage{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abbreviations}
\makenomenclature 

\begin{document}
    \printnomenclature

    \section{Experimental Part}
    \textit{Synthesis of some compound \textbf{(aa)}}\\ %E13
    To a solution of 2-bromo-5-methoxybenzoic acid in DMF \nomenclature{DMF}{Dimethylformamide} (33 mL) is added CuCN\nomenclature{CuCN}{Copper Cyanide}. 
\end{document}
```

and run `arara thesis.tex`. That works and you don't have to waste more thoughts on the `makeindex` compiling routine of `nomencl`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick answer. I therefore have to had those % arara before, that I did, but when you say "run arara thesis.tex" I don't get it...  Do I have to type it in the command window? Cause I can't type in there.

(when I said I'm a beginner, well, it's really really true :P)

Comment: No Problem. I don't know TeXShop, sorry. But you may try this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97926 If it does not work, you can open some terminal window, go to your folder and run arara thesis.tex in there. I hope, you have arara already installed in your distro. Good luck.