# flow for using nomencl package

Tags: glossaries, nomencl

Someone mentioned in
[How to create glossary entries for custom notation with arguments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440324/how-to-create-glossary-entries-for-custom-notation-with-arguments/440330#440330)
that the `nomencl` package can do almost what I want the `glossaries` package to do.   Has someone used this package recently?   I can't figure out how to make it work.

Compiling the following code with latexmk -pdf creates a file thest.nlo,
but then complains about a missing test.nls file.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}   
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}    
\section{A test section}
\label{lab.test.section}

\nomenclature{$\bigcap$}{Unary intersection operator. Section~\ref{lab.test.section}, page~\pageref{lab.test.section}.}

If $V$ is a set of subsets of $U$, then we define the unary
$\bigcap$ operator as follows...

\appendix

\chapter{Test chapter}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

And the documentation 
https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Nomenclatures
doesn't seem to mention needing to run any external program.

I took a look at
[How to compile \nomencl in order to have a list of abbreviation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148648/how-to-compile-nomencl-in-order-to-have-a-list-of-abbreviation)
But when I try to run

```
makeindex test.nlo -s test.ist -o test.nls
```

I get an error: `Index style file test.ist` not found.

Comment: Your code works fine when I throw it in my editor and compile it there. I am using Overleaf v2 with pdfLaTeX as the compiler.

Comment: It is quite complicated knowing which latex frontend to use.  Different ones do different things and not others apparently.   I'm currently changing from texi2dvi to latexmk.  Are you suggesting I don't use latexmk, but rather pdfLaTeX instead?     Isn't it the case that pdfLaTeX doesn't know how to resolve the references, thus I need to run something like latexmk instead?

Comment: So I tried with pdfLaTex, and it does not create any nomenclature output.  Flexo013, can you verify that when you ran it, that it indeed created the correct content of Appendix A complete with title "Test chapter" and the simply nomenclature list of one item?

Comment: Try `makeindex test.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o test.nls` instead. Then run pdflatex on `test.tex` again

Comment: @JimNewton [The pdf output  looks like this (very zoomed out)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuJn9.png)

Comment: Hi Troy, when i try to run makeindex as you suggest, I get the error message: Index style file test.ist not found.
And then a usage string.

Comment: I said `nomencl.ist`, not `test.ist`.

Comment: ahhh.   need to check my eyes.   when I use 's nomencl.ist it works much better.  Thanks.